# Sharing & Permission error in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, permissions, operating-system, sharing

### Unfortunately, I've got myself into a situation.

I installed XAMPP into Mac OS X and tried to set up the localhost server and then installed Wordpress in it. It was giving me the error `couldn't create the directory.`

Upon researching a little bit I've got an idea to change the permission to 0755 so, it will be sorted out. When I was changing permission in Mac OS X, I deleted main users and in everyone, it is No Access option.

I can't delete this folder even I uninstalled the software and tried to install it again but it is still not granting me access.

What can I do in this situation?

[Image of httdoc in XAMPP with error sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DPrh.png)

Comment: Bumping up, if anyone got any idea how to sort out this error?

Comment: Bumping up, still having that issue!

Comment: Bumping up, still having the same issue!